# Does document.execCommand('copy') require human interaction first?

Tags: javascript, copy

This works when I press the copy button. It copies "Hurray!" into the clipboard.
But it doesn't work when the page loads even though I have `$('#mycopy').click()`. I'm trying to make it so that the user doesn't have to press the copy button.

```js
document.getElementById('mycopy').addEventListener('click', copyFunction, true)

function copyFunction() {
 var inp = document.getElementById('mytextarea')
 console.log(inp)
 inp.select()
 document.execCommand('copy')
}
$('#mycopy').click()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="mycopy">copy</button>
<textarea id="mytextarea">Hurray!</textarea>
<textarea autofocus rows="10">Copy something other than Hurray! into your clipboard and then load the page.</textarea>
```

Comment: yes, it requires actual interaction, not faked interaction - these limitations are there to protect you from malicious sites